Using PyQt6 and QSqlRelationalTableModel I am unable to display a TableView of a Many to Many table with ComboBox for foreign keys
Trying to add/edit data in a linking table "RecipeIngredients" with the following columns: Id (primary key), RecipeId (foreign key), IngredientId (foreign key), QuantityTypeId (foreign key), Quantity (real data type) using Sqlite database.  I want the TableView list to display a ComboBox with the appropriate text value for each of the foreign key columns allowing me to choose the appropriate Recipe, Ingredient, QuantityType (such as oz, cups, tsp, etc), and a QLineEdit to enter the quantity.  Using Model.setRelation to specify the relations between tables doesn't work.  I see the appropriate column names in the view but not as ComboBoxes.  I tried to duplicate code from another script using only one foreign key which worked appropriately but can't seem to translate it correctly to this table with three foreign keys.
I essentially described that in the previous block of text.  I will include my code below:
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt6 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt6 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt6 import QtSql as qts

class DateDelegate(qtw.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, proxyModelIndex):
        # make sure to explicitly set the parent
        # otherwise it pops up in a top-level window!
        date_inp = qtw.QDateEdit(parent, calendarPopup=True)
        return date_inp

class RecipeIngredientForm(qtw.QWidget):
    """Form to display/edit all info about an Ingredient"""

    def __init__(self, RecipeIngredientModel):
        super().__init__()
        self.setLayout(qtw.QFormLayout())

        # RecipeIngredient Fields
        self.Recipe = qtw.QComboBox()
        self.layout().addRow('Recipe: ', self.Recipe)
        self.Ingredient = qtw.QComboBox()
        self.layout().addRow('Ingredient: ', self.Ingredient)
        self.QuantityType = qtw.QComboBox()
        self.layout().addRow('QuantityType: ', self.QuantityType)
        self.Quantity = qtw.QLineEdit()
        self.layout().addRow('Quantity: ', self.Quantity)

        # Map the RecipeIngredient fields
        self.RecipeIngredientModel = RecipeIngredientModel
        self.mapper = qtw.QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setModel(self.RecipeIngredientModel)
        self.mapper.setItemDelegate(
            qts.QSqlRelationalDelegate(self))
        
        self.mapper.addMapping(
            self.Recipe,
            self.RecipeIngredientModel.fieldIndex('RecipeId')
        )
        self.mapper.addMapping(
            self.QuantityType,
            self.RecipeIngredientModel.fieldIndex('QuantityTypeId')
        )
        self.mapper.addMapping(
            self.Ingredient,
            self.RecipeIngredientModel.fieldIndex('IngredientId') 
        )
        self.mapper.addMapping(
            self.Quantity,
            self.RecipeIngredientModel.fieldIndex('Quantity')
        )

        # set model for the Recipe table and setup the combo box
        RecipeModel = RecipeIngredientModel.relationModel(
            self.RecipeIngredientModel.fieldIndex('Name'))
        self.Recipe.setModel(RecipeModel)
        self.Recipe.setModelColumn(1)

        # set model for the Ingredient table and setup the ComboBox
        IngredientModel = RecipeIngredientModel.relationModel(
            self.RecipeIngredientModel.fieldIndex('Description'))
        self.Ingredient.setModel(IngredientModel)
        self.Ingredient.setModelColumn(1)
        
        # set model for the QuantityType tables and setup the ComboBox
        QuantityTypeModel = RecipeIngredientModel.relationModel(
            self.RecipeIngredientModel.fieldIndex('Unit'))
        self.QuantityType.setModel(QuantityTypeModel)
        self.QuantityType.setModelColumn(1)


    def ShowRecipeIngredient(self, RecipeIngredientIndex):
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(RecipeIngredientIndex.row())
       
class Mainwindow(qtw.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        """ MainWindow constructor"""
        super().__init__()
        # Main UI code goes here

        self.stack = qtw.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stack)

        # connect to database
        self.db = qts.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.db.setDatabaseName('THMMenus.db')
        if not self.db.open():
            error = self.db.lastError().text()
            qtw.QMessageBox.critical(
                None, 'DB Connection Error',
                'Could not open database file: '
                f'{error}')
            sys.exit(1)

        required_tables = {'RecipeIngredient','Recipe', 'Ingredient', 'QuantityType'}
        tables = self.db.tables()
        missing_tables = required_tables - set(tables)
        if missing_tables:
            qtw.QMessageBox.critical(
                None, 'DB Integrity Error', 'Missing tables, please repair DB: '
                f'(missing_tables)')
            sys.exit(1)

        #create the models
        self.RecipeIngredientModel = qts.QSqlRelationalTableModel()
        self.RecipeIngredientModel.setTable('RecipeIngredient')
        self.RecipeIngredientModel.setRelation(
            self.RecipeIngredientModel.fieldIndex('RecipeId'),
            qts.QSqlRelation('Recipe', 'Id', 'Name')
        )
        self.RecipeIngredientModel.setRelation(
            self.RecipeIngredientModel.fieldIndex('IngredientId'),
            qts.QSqlRelation('Ingredient', 'Id', 'Description')
        )

        self.RecipeIngredientModel.setRelation(
            self.RecipeIngredientModel.fieldIndex('QuantityTypeId'),
            qts.QSqlRelation('QuantityType', 'Id', 'Unit')
        )

        self.RecipeIngredientModel.setEditStrategy(qts.QSqlTableModel.EditStrategy.OnFieldChange)
        self.RecipeIngredientList = qtw.QTableView()
        self.RecipeIngredientList.setModel(self.RecipeIngredientModel)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.RecipeIngredientList)

        self.RecipeIngredientModel.select()
        self.ShowList()

        #inserting and deleting rows.
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Controls')
        toolbar.addAction('Delete Recipe Ingredient', self.DeleteRecipeIngredient)
        toolbar.addAction('Add Recipe Ingredient', self.AddRecipeIngredient)

        self.RecipeIngredientList.setItemDelegate(qts.QSqlRelationalDelegate())
        self.RecipeIngredientList.setSortingEnabled(True)

        # The RecipeIngredient form
        self.RecipeIngredientForm = RecipeIngredientForm(
            self.RecipeIngredientModel
        )
        self.stack.addWidget(self.RecipeIngredientForm)
        self.RecipeIngredientList.doubleClicked.connect(
            self.RecipeIngredientForm.ShowRecipeIngredient)
        self.RecipeIngredientList.doubleClicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stack.setCurrentWidget(self.RecipeIngredientForm))
        
        toolbar.addAction("Back to list", self.ShowList)

        # Code ends here
        self.show()

    def DeleteRecipeIngredient(self):
        selected = self.RecipeIngredientList.selectedIndexes()
        for index in selected or []:
            self.RecipeIngredientModel.removeRow(index.row())
        self.RecipeIngredientModel.select()

    def AddRecipeIngredient(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentWidget(self.RecipeIngredientList)
        self.RecipeIngredientModel.insertRows(
            self.RecipeIngredientModel.rowCount(), 1)

    def ShowList(self):
        self.RecipeIngredientList.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.RecipeIngredientList.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.stack.setCurrentWidget(self.RecipeIngredientList)

if __name__== '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = Mainwindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Item editors are not shown automatically, in order to display them the user has to do one of the view's editTriggers which by default are DoubleClicked and EditKeyPressed, or the code has to explicitly call openPersistentEditor(). Since the connection to the doubleClicked signal switches to a different page (thus hiding the table) and openPersistentEditor() is never called, no combo box is being shown.

DoubleClicking on an existing row shows a form with the appropriate related values allowing me to edit the row though the only way I can get back to the listview is by clicking "Back to list" however for the row I edited, the value I chose is not displayed.  When I click on the toolbar item "Add Recipe Ingredient", a blank row is displayed in the list.  Then when I doubleclick on the blank line, the form is displayed with the Recipe combobox already selected (it shouldn't be) and the QuantiyType selected (it shouldn't be) while the Ingredient combobox is empty (it should be) and quantity

Also have a question about the RecipeIngredientModel.setEditStrategy method or property.  I originally had it set to .onFieldChange.  I'm not sure what field is meant.  Another setting is .OnManualSubmit.  I'm not sure how to initiate the OnManualSubmit.  Do I need a button on the form (not the list) to activate it.  Sorry, this is all new and the documentation is not very helpful.  The current code is working...sort of but not quite correct.  One more question, when I click on the Ingredient ComboBox, the list of possible ingredients is displayed but is not sorted alphabetically, which i want

I understand your disorientation, but the fact that you're asking so many (and completely legitimate) questions shows that you may need to do a few steps back. The Qt model/view framework is very extensive and expandable, but this also means that knowing how to use its extended features (like SQL support, the relational table model and its delegate) requires having enough knowledge and experience with its basics (such as item delegate behavior and how their data is submit). Simply put (and a bit harsh, I know) if you don't know what's the purpose and behavior of the edit strategy, you cannot »

» try to do something more complex that deals with advanced delegates, SQL data submit or focus changes that may cause different results depending on the context. For instance, you're asking about a sorted list in the combobox, but it probably shows the contents based on how they exist in the related SQL table, and SQL is, by nature, not sorted; this means that you probably need a subclass that actually sets a QSortFilterProxyModel for the editor created in the delegate, based on the table relation. What you want to do can be done, but you have to be patient with your learning and do »

» one step at a time. Try to identify every key aspect of your problem(s), then create small experiments specifically and individually focused on each one of those aspects. I know that the documentation doesn't seem to help, especially considering that the starting points (for instance, the model/view guide) may seem overwhelming, and finding what you think you're looking for seems like looking for the proverbial needle in a haystack. In reality, it's generally well written, you just need to be patient and follow it progressively.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

To musicamante, thank you for your suggestions.  Do you have any  suggestions re: books on the ModelView framework in PyQt6 or other online examples/documentation that would be helpful?  I've read Chapter 9 of Mastering GUI Programming  with Python which deals with a very simple model that helped me get started but with all simple models, once you stray from the exact scenario of the example, you run into problems.  I was a programmer for 25 years starting with Basic, then Foxpro, then Visual Basic, Visual C#, Visual Studio, ASP.Net.  I've been retired for nearly 10 years but still learning.

@AllenWegele Sorry but I've no reference book to suggest: I've learned Qt the hard way, especially in the beginning (mostly stubbornly, as I presumptuously refused to be patient with the documentation, which is actually well written). My suggestion is to be patient (more than I was, and I know I sound hypocrite), study the documentation and individually learn each aspect one step at a time. Start by creating very basic codes that test what you learnt in each one of your last steps (imagine abstract scenarios where they may be useful) then experiment with them to check your understandings.

@AllenWegele Then, since you're used to different languages and syntaxes, you shouldn't have many problems reading C++ code: every time you're curious about some aspect, or you want to know more about what a function or class actually does, you could then check the Qt sources (which are usually quite well written): they are available at https://code.qt.io/cgit/ but a more semantic code browser is also available at https://codebrowser.dev/, which is a great and extremely insightful learning source. PS: please remember to use @username when replying, otherwise we won't receive notifications.
